# Error while converting String to Integer in android

Tags: java, android, string, integer

I am trying to convert string value into int but it give me error:

> android.content.res.resources$notfoundexception string resource id #0x16 <

I tried parsing like:

```
       String date = "29-30-2098";
       String[] d = date.split("-");
       int di = Integer.parseInt(d[1]);
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, di, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

if i give String data type to "di" then it print the correct value. But when i try to parse it to Int it give the error
And i also tried by using `ValueOf();` but in all methods it give me error.
Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.myanxietyjournal, PID: 8830
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myanxietyjournal/com.myanxietyjournal.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1e
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2793)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1e
                  at android.content.res.HwResources.getText(HwResources.java:442)
                  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:307)
                  at com.myanxietyjournal.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6915)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2746)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1567) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Comment: `s` is being initialized differently. You are not *hardcoding* an integer to it. Show us what you are trying to do :)

Comment: I am trying to get String value from firebase and i need to convert that value into integer.

Comment: Try logging the value that you are getting from firebase. There is very little that could go wrong in converting "1234" ( or any such string) as an int.. Also take a look at the exception - it isn't NumberFormatException

Comment: @MsbSays The code you posted does not produce this error, so if you want to get help, post the actual code.

Comment: It is giving me the same error

Comment: i update the question

Comment: Your error and code are no where related to each other. Perhaps you might want to debug and see where the actual error is occured.

Comment: i got this exception in catch block

Comment: Your error is of resource not found. Check the line of error.

Comment: In the Toast line it is giving the error

Comment: Every time i parse into int it gives me same error. I couldnt find any solution

Comment: Toast accepts a `String`, or a resource identifier. Passing an `int` there means you want it to show the `string` resource with provided identifier. To show an integer in the toast, first convert it to string.

Answer (score 0):

There are two versions of `makeText`:

- [`makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#makeText(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int))
- [`makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast#makeText(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int))

The first one takes a `String` as the second parameter, and shows the message in the string to the user.

The second one takes a **resource id** as the second parameter, tries to lookup the resource, and fails because you don't have a resource with that id.

To show the `int` *value* to the user, you need to convert it to string first, e.g. `String.valueOf(di)`.